Intuition for bounds of Adaptive Conformal Inference
I have been reading the paper by E. Candès and Gibbs about Adaptive Conformal Inference (here is the original papel). The main idea is to update the miscoverage level $\alpha_t$ as
$
\begin{cases}
\widehat{C}_{\alpha_t}\left(x_t\right) & =\left[\hat{\mu}\left(x_t\right) \pm \widehat{Q}_{1-\alpha_t}\left(S_{\mathrm{Cal}_t}\right)\right] \\
\alpha_{t+1} & =\alpha_t+\gamma\left(\alpha-\mathbb{1}\left\{y_t \notin \widehat{C}_{\alpha_t}\left(x_t\right)\right\}\right)
\end{cases}
$
Where $\widehat{C}_{\alpha_t}\left(x_t\right)$ is a prediction interval for $y_{t}$ based on the available data $x_t$ at time t, $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $\gamma \geq0$. They claim that the sequence of $\alpha_t$ is bounded between $[-\gamma, 1 + \gamma]$, I already read the proof and they prove it by contradiction but I have been trying to get an intuition of how to get the actual bounds because I will need to do something like this in the future. If someone has seen some like this before (not necessarily the same) it would be good to know about it or to get a good reference because I don't even know how to look for a similar problem online.
Thanks to all!
